# Create Geo Index and query near

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I am using azure cosmos db how to create index and query nearest top 10 user if the document is like this, in C#:

```
{
  "_id" : "146138792054898475572",
  "email" : "abc@gmail.com",
  "firstName" : "abc",
  "lastName" : "abc",
  "loc" : {
    "lat" : 31.5200788,
    "lng" : 74.3236112
  },
  "gender" : "Male",
  "deviceId" : "YWg8crAjZLCrV",
  "createdDate" : ISODate("2017-06-11T11:35:41.601Z"),
  "updatedDate" : ISODate("2017-06-17T17:33:10.743Z")
}
```

Query:

```
db.User.find(
   {
      "loc":
        { $near :
           {
             $geometry: { type: "Point",  coordinates: [ 31.5200788, 74.3236112 ] },
             $minDistance: 1000,
             $maxDistance: 5000
           }
        }
   }
)
```

Comment: So you're trying to do a spatial query? What did you try? You've only shown your document, with no query attempt, no output, and no specific error. Is your database set to DocumentDB API or MongoDB API? That makes a big difference. I'm guessing MongoDB based on the properties and tag, but you should confirm.

Comment: @DavidMakogon querry added

Comment: no result shown when I tried this

Comment: Have you confirmed that this query works on a local mongodb install?

Comment: yes but no result found

Comment: What is the index created on? Did you possibly create more than one index? If so then that's a problem. It should be on `.createIndex({"loc": "2dsphere" })`. Check the indexes with `.getIndexes()` and remove any additional geo indexes or preferably `.dropIndexes()` and start again. @DavidMakogon is correct and your order is the wrong way around. You really should be using [GeoJSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/) format for storage and not the "legacy" format anyway.

Comment: @NeilLunn in Azure Cosmos DB I cant able to create index for geo indexes and in the answer below when i execute the $geonear query it shows me error that $geoNear is not supported

Comment: @NeilLunn when i execute the query it runs locally but not  show me correct result(no result) in Azure cosmos DB

Comment: @MalikKashmiri The answer clearly states that CosmosDB is not MongoDB, and that in fact NO Aggregation operations are in fact supported by CosmosDB at all at this time. It is also "correct" in stating that your present structure is not valid for performing a `$near` query and in fact where you correct your structure a `$near` query is indeed supported by CosmosDB. Therefore the answer is "correct" and should be accepted as such.Your structure needs to be corrected as shown in order for queries to work. Also, comments related to an answer should be given on the answer itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here that mostly relate to how you have stored the documents. MongoDB supports storing a coordinate point in one of three formats:

- **Legacy coordinate pairs as array** Where the data is listed in longitude and then latitude order

  ```
  [ 74.3236112, 31.5200788 ]
  ```
- **Legacy coordinate pairs as an object** Where the data can be organized by named keys, but these **must** be ordered and named explicitly as **"lon"** and **"lat"** respectively "in order":

  ```
  { "lon": 74.3236112, "lat": 31.5200788 }
  ```
- **As [GeoJSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/) format** where the data stored can be any valid GeoJSON object format. For a **"Point"** type this is:

  ```
  {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [ 74.3236112, 31.5200788 ]
  }
  ```

To demonstrate I have a collection with your sample document in four different formats. We are going to create an index on that collection with `.createIndex({ "loc": "2dsphere" })` and then use the aggregation pipeline [`$geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) to query and return the actual distance from the queried point:

```
db.geotest.aggregate([
  { "$geoNear": {
    "near": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [ 74.3236112, 31.5200788 ]
    },
    "spherical": true,
    "distanceField": "distance"
  }}
])
```

Shows the four different formats and the calculated distance from the query. Note that only the two **"valid"** formats return the correct distance of `0` from the query location:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5945f800b4051c7e52c90d1c"),
        "email" : "abc@gmail.com",
        "firstName" : "abc",
        "lastName" : "abc",
        "loc" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [
                        74.3236112,
                        31.5200788
                ]
        },
        "gender" : "Male",
        "deviceId" : "YWg8crAjZLCrV",
        "createdDate" : ISODate("2017-06-11T11:35:41.601Z"),
        "updatedDate" : ISODate("2017-06-17T17:33:10.743Z"),
        "distance" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5945f8f6b4051c7e52c90d1e"),
        "email" : "abc@gmail.com",
        "firstName" : "abc",
        "lastName" : "abc",
        "loc" : {
                "lon" : 74.3236112,
                "lat" : 31.5200788
        },
        "gender" : "Male",
        "deviceId" : "YWg8crAjZLCrV",
        "createdDate" : ISODate("2017-06-11T11:35:41.601Z"),
        "updatedDate" : ISODate("2017-06-17T17:33:10.743Z"),
        "distance" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : "146138792054898475572",
        "email" : "abc@gmail.com",
        "firstName" : "abc",
        "lastName" : "abc",
        "loc" : {
                "lat" : 31.5200788,
                "lng" : 74.3236112
        },
        "gender" : "Male",
        "deviceId" : "YWg8crAjZLCrV",
        "createdDate" : ISODate("2017-06-11T11:35:41.601Z"),
        "updatedDate" : ISODate("2017-06-17T17:33:10.743Z"),
        "distance" : 5315650.25629941
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5945f8b7b4051c7e52c90d1d"),
        "email" : "abc@gmail.com",
        "firstName" : "abc",
        "lastName" : "abc",
        "loc" : {
                "lat" : 31.5200788,
                "lon" : 74.3236112
        },
        "gender" : "Male",
        "deviceId" : "YWg8crAjZLCrV",
        "createdDate" : ISODate("2017-06-11T11:35:41.601Z"),
        "updatedDate" : ISODate("2017-06-17T17:33:10.743Z"),
        "distance" : 5315650.25629941
}
```

So in order to query correctly, you need a **"valid"** format for the index. I personally recommend using the GeoJSON format as it is widely used as a standard, and also gives you the option of storing any valid GeoJSON object as opposed to just *"point coordinates"*.

You can convert the data with an operation like the following:

```
var ops = [];

db.User.find({ 
  "loc.lng": { "$exists": true }, 
  "loc.lat": { "$exists": true }
}).forEach(function(doc) {
  ops.push({
    "updateOne": {
      "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
      "update": {
        "$set": {
          "loc": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [ doc.loc.lng, doc.loc.lat ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
  if ( ops.length >= 1000 ) {
    db.User.bulkWrite(ops);
    ops = [];
  }
});

if ( ops.length > 0 ) {
  db.User.bulkWrite(ops);
  ops = [];
}
```

This will rewrite the `"loc"` data to the corrected format so the index and query will work.

You should in fact really do a `.dropIndexes()` on the collection before updating to save on the write cost and then re-create the index once complete. It's not a necessary step, but it would be recommended.

**N.B** Also the `$minDistace` argument here with data corrected would actually still exclude the result since as demonstrated the actual distance from the queried point ( which is the same coordinates ) is `0`. So remove that constraint on testing, or better yet test with [`$geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) as demonstrated.

**Also Note** There is mention of DocumentDB, which does not support the aggregation pipeline protocols. The examples here work against MongoDB without issue, and are mainly here to demonstrate the "format" problem with the data. Regular `$near` and [other geospatial general queries are supported](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/ef5e67f2-761e-4b12-9bd8-630a2415883c/geospatial-queries-on-documentdb-with-mongo-support?forum=AzureDocumentDB). But the data must be in the correct supported format.

Answer (score 2):

Your coordinates are backward. Per MongoDB [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geometry/):

> If you use longitude and latitude, specify coordinates in order of:
>   longitude, latitude.

You need to reverse your coordinates:

```
db.User.find(
   {
      "loc":
        { $near :
           {
             $geometry: { type: "Point",  coordinates: [ 74.3236112, 31.5200788 ] },
             $minDistance: 1000,
             $maxDistance: 5000
           }
        }
   }
)
```

Also, in your `loc` property, the ordering is longitude, latitude (yours is reversed in the doc you showed).

Comment: still no result

Comment: @MalikKashmiri The promlem here is `$maxDistance: 5000` since the point given in the document in the question is "further" than the constraint provided. Remove that with the corrected order of longitude then latitude and the query returns the document.